# Azure Service Bus - estimation of the number of brokered connection

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I was trying to estimate no. of brokered connections while arrive at pricing for Service Bus (**STANDARD TIER**) for the following scenario:

- There are `32 clients` sending messages to/ receiving messages from a Service Bus queue through AMQP protocol.
- Each client connects to the Service Bus several times in an hour, with duration of a single connection (including timeout) ~= `1 minute`.

I understand from [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/service-bus/) that Microsoft charges based on the peak number of concurrent brokered connections:

> Microsoft charges for the peak number of concurrent brokered
>   connections that exceed the included quantity (1,000 in the standard
>   and premium tier).

Now for one month, what will be the no. of brokered connections?

- **is it 32?** - as, at any given point of time, there are *only 32 peak live connections* and based on the formula given in Pricing document. Therefore total connections being `32 connections * 24 hours per day * 30.5 days / 730 = 32`.
- or **is it 1920?** - as, in an hour, *each client connects to Service Bus 60 times* (no. of minutes in an hour [=60] / duration of a single connection [=1]). Therefore, total connections being `(32 * 60) connections * 24 hours per day * 30,5 days / 730 = 1920`.

Please help me understand how to calculate the no. of brokered connections in this scenario!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it will be 32 since there is hourly metering on Service Bus. (Even if it was per minute metering, it would still be 32).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034521/ashish-chhabria), thanks for the clarification!